# hadoop - what is the best way to fetch data from a very big sequence file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a very big hadoop sequence file in the hdfs.
what is the best way to fetch data from it? ie, select records and etc..

can it be done by hive?
how can i create a table in hive from a sequence file?

thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the external tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need 'quick' access to the data you should either consider loading the data into a datastore of some sort (DB or a noSQL store such as HBase, Accumulo).

Another option (if you can re-write your data) is to look into using a [MapFile](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html) - this creates an index for the keys in your sequence file and provides *quicker* access to the data compared to full file scanning.

Otherwise if you want to use Hive, there's a thread on the hive mailing list about this exact subject:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/hive-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg00173.html

Comment: My focus is not about 'quick' in concern of performence. Its 'quick' in concern of development. I just need to so some random analysis. prefer not to write mapreduce for each one or for each time I want to.
If I use hbase, how can I load a sequence file to hbase?

Comment: If random analysis is what you're after then i'd look into using Pig. As for loading sequence file into hbase, you'll either need to write a map reduce job to read the seq files and write the data to hbase, or change your output format to be `HFileOutputFormat` and then bulk load.